# Volume of surface revolution of curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $(g(s),0, f(s))$ be the curve on $xz$ plane. Let $S$ be a surface of revolution obtained by rotating the curve around $x$ axis.

Then I know how to compute the surface area and Gaussian curvature of $S$.

i.e., From direct computation, I know its Gaussian curvature and Mean curvature is given by $K = -\frac{f''}{f}$ and $2H = \frac{g'}{f} - \frac{f''}{g}$.

but How one can compute the volume of the region bounded by $S$ and $yz$ plane? can you give me some explicit equation in terms of $g, f$?

Comment: Do it the way you do the volume of revolution in beginning calculus. Slice perpendicular to the $x$-axis.

Comment: @TedShifrin, In 2d usually we do the volume of revolution through $x$ axis by $\int \pi y^2 dx$. But I am confused with 3d. In 3d, the slice perpendicular to the x-axis will be $yz$ plane, then how one can integrate curve on $yz$ plane along with $x$ axis?

Comment: But that *is* in 3D, of course. You rotate the curve in the $xy$-plane around the $x$-axis, so cross-sections are in planes parallel to the $yz$-plane. The curve here is in the $xz$-plane to start with, but it makes no difference. You want to integrate $\pi (\text{radius}^2)$ with respect to $x$.