# Volume of revolution $ \gamma(t) = \left(\log\left(\cot\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) \right) - \cos(t), \sin(t),0\right)$ rotated by $x$ axis

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

The reason why I post the question [Volume of surface revolution of curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3575713/volume-of-surface-revolution-of-curve) is to solve following problem.

Consider the curve on $xy$-plane 
\begin{align}
  \gamma(t) = \left(\log\left(\cot\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) \right) - \cos(t), \sin(t),0\right), \quad t\in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}).  
\end{align}
Let $S$ be a surface of revolution obtained by rotating the curve $\gamma$ around $x$-axis. Compute the volume of the region bounded by $S$ and $yz$ plane.

From @Ted Shifrin comment, here is my following (I set $y=\sin(t)$)
\begin{align}
  V_S = \int \pi y^2 dx =  \pi \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(-\sin(t) + \sin^3(t) \right) dt =  - \pi \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(t) \cos^2(t) dt =  - \frac{\pi}{3}  
\end{align}
It seems weired that I have negative values. Is this the right procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That formula is correct because it so happens that the curve (roughly) goes between the "points" $(+\infty, 0)$ and $(0,1)$, so we do not need to resort to the shells method, which would technically be the correct approach to get the volume between the surface and the $yz$ plane. To compare, the two formulas for the volumes would be

$$V = \int \pi \: y^2 \: dx = \int 2\pi \:x \: y \:dy$$

But looking at the formulas for $x$ and $y$, it is obvious that we would benefit from incorporating $dx$ instead of $x$. Calculating $dx$ we get that

$$dx = (-\csc t + \sin t) \: dt$$

Notice that on the interval $\left( 0 , \frac{\pi}{2} \right) $ the quantity in parentheses is always negative. The curious feature about parametric equations is that direction matters, and we have to pick the "correct" direction in order to accumulate our measures in the right order.

This makes the final integral

$$V = \pi\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^0 -\cos^2 t \sin t\:dt = \frac{\pi}{3}$$